# Why does a Spark Stage with Chained withColumn window aggregations keep running OOM even with smaller partitions?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr, distributed-computing

I have a Stage in spark Job that contains a long chain of window aggregations that keep failing no matter how many partitions I add.

My cluster configuration is a ```48 Node(r5.2xlarge) EMR Cluster each with:

- 64 gb Memory
- 8vCpu Each

The spark 2.4 settings are set to:

- executor memory 16g, overhead 2g
- driver memory 8g, overhead 2g
- AutoBroadcast -1

The execution plan looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONzVu.png)

The core of the tasks is to add new columns using `withColumn` aggregations over 2 types of partitions. I've repartitioned the dataset prior by 2 of the 4 commons partitions keys; which has avoided any shuffles.

```
w = W.partitionBy("a","b","c").orderBy("d")
w_2 = W.partitionBy("a","c").orderBy("d")

calculated_outcome = data.withColumn("x",F.when(
                F.col("data_column").isNotNull(),
                F.sum("sum_columns").over(w.rangeBetween(-90, 0)),
            ).otherwise(None)).withColumn("x_2",F.when(
                F.col("data_column").isNotNull(),
                F.sum("sum_columns").over(w.rangeBetween(-60, 0)),
            ).otherwise(None)).withColumn("x_3",F.when(
                F.col("data_column").isNotNull(),
                F.sum("sum_columns").over(w.rangeBetween(-30, 0)),
            ).otherwise(None)).withColumn("y",F.when(
                F.col("data_column_2").isNotNull(),
                F.sum("sum_columns").over(w.rangeBetween(-90, 0)),
            ).otherwise(None)).withColumn("y_2",F.when(
                F.col("data_column").isNotNull(),
                F.sum("sum_columns").over(w.rangeBetween(-60, 0)),
            ).otherwise(None)).withColumn("y_3",F.when(
                F.col("data_column").isNotNull(),
                F.sum("sum_columns").over(w.rangeBetween(-30, 0)),
            ).otherwise(None)).withColumn("z",F.when(
                F.col("data_column").isNotNull(),
                F.sum("sum_columns").over(w.rangeBetween(-90, 0)),
            ).otherwise(None)).withColumn("z_2",F.when(
                F.col("data_column").isNotNull(),
                F.sum("sum_columns").over(w.rangeBetween(-60, 0)),
            ).otherwise(None)).withColumn("z_3",F.when(
                F.col("data_column").isNotNull(),
                F.sum("sum_columns").over(w.rangeBetween(-30, 0)),
            ).otherwise(None))

return calculated_outcome.groupBy("a","b","c").agg(*F.sum([x for x in [columns_to_sum_avg_etc]))
```

In the example above, I've given what mostly transformations are about(sum,avg,lag). In total there are 11 withColumns in the window function and about 15 aggregated columns in the following groupie.

Happy to add more information if needed!

Comment: Can you add the code here just to get more clarity on what you are doing?

Comment: Added an example of the transformation I'm trying to achieve

Comment: Does not strike me as easy for Catalyst

Comment: would you try to cache the `calculated_outcome` before `groupBy`? OOM might come from window functions not aggregation

Comment: Could you put the exception stack please ?

Answer (score 0):

In the ScalaDoc for Scala API there is the following note for the method `withColumn`:

> this method introduces a projection internally. Therefore, calling it multiple times for instance, via loops in order to add multiple columns can generate big plans which can cause performance issues and even `StackOverflowException`. To avoid this, use `select` with the multiple columns at once.

Probably the same applies to Python API, it might get even worse since Python is not native to JVM.